Problems trying to update ANTLR's default TypeScript grammar
I'm trying to update the default ANTLR TypeScript grammar since it seems to support only TypeScript up to version 2.7.
One of the new constructions is the conditional types, which demanded me to alter the type_ rule and create the conditionalType rule:
type_
: unionOrIntersectionOrPrimaryType
| functionType
| constructorType
| typeGeneric
| typeName typeGeneric
| literal
| conditionalType
;

conditionalType
: typeName constraint QuestionMark type_ Colon type_
;

However, when parsing the following code, it apperantly does not recognize the array bracktes in any[]:
type Boxed<T> = T extends any[] ? BoxedArray<T[number]> : BoxedValue<T>;
The error is:

Syntax error at line 1, column 29: missing '?' at '['

Considering the rules at the end of this post, I would expect it to derive a tree, more or less, like this:
(typeAliasDeclaration ... = (type_ (conditionalType (typeName T) (constraint extends (type_(unionOrIntersectionOrPrimaryType(primaryType (ArrayPrimType (predefinedType any) [])))))
But it seems the parser is selecting the rule PredefinedPrimType directly after unionOrIntersectionOrPrimaryType, ignoring the recusive production ArrayPrimType.
I've tried putting the #ArrayPrimType production before the #PredefinedPrimType production in the rule primaryType, and even removing #PredefinedPrimType production. I also tried the #ArrayPrimType production without the semantic predicate, as well as with the semantic predicate at the end of the production, like this | primaryType '[' ']' { self.notLineTerminator}? #ArrayPrimType. None of those tries have worked so far. Can anyone help me with this scenario?
: 'type' Identifier typeParameters? '=' type_ SemiColon
;

type_
: unionOrIntersectionOrPrimaryType
| functionType
| constructorType
| typeGeneric
| typeName typeGeneric
| literal
| conditionalType
;

conditionalType
: typeName constraint QuestionMark type_ Colon type_
;

constraint
: 'extends' type_
;

unionOrIntersectionOrPrimaryType
: unionOrIntersectionOrPrimaryType '|' unionOrIntersectionOrPrimaryType #Union
| unionOrIntersectionOrPrimaryType '&' unionOrIntersectionOrPrimaryType #Intersection
| primaryType #Primary
;

primaryType
: '(' type_ ')' #ParenthesizedPrimType
| predefinedType #PredefinedPrimType
| typeReference #ReferencePrimType
| objectType #ObjectPrimType
| primaryType { self.notLineTerminator}? '[' ']' #ArrayPrimType
| '[' tupleElementTypes ']' #TuplePrimType
| typeQuery #QueryPrimType
| This #ThisPrimType
| typeReference Is primaryType #RedefinitionOfType
;

predefinedType
: Any
| Number
| Boolean
| String
| Symbol
| Void
| Unique Symbol // typescript v2.7
;```


First, I would check the semantic predicate { self.notLineTerminator}? for label ArrayPrimType. Remove the predicate and try your input example. A semantic predicate in the middle of an alt will not work, so this grammar looks wrong. It must be at the beginning of the alt.

Sorry @kaby76 I forgot to mention that I already tried the ArrayPrimType production without the semantic predicate at all, and also with the semantic predicate at the end of the production, like this: | primaryType '[' ']' { self.notLineTerminator}? #ArrayPrimType. The error persisted the same.
